# Screenshot from an inactive to an RDP session

Tags: winapi, directshow, rdp

I need to do a screen capture using DirectShow from the RDP session, but the problem is that the seizure does not occur if the disconnect from the session. Is there any way to make a drawing of the session to continue even after you disconnect rdp session?

Comment: I would expect absence of "screen" activity on a disconnected session, why would it be there? You should rather handle connection/disconnection events on your application and update the screen capture activity respectively.

Comment: RDP session is not active, but it holds a certain program, which periodically need to take screenshots.

Comment: But this app does not repaint itself - so you cannot capture this either. You can inject yourself into this app process and issue `WM_PAINT` messages from there, to force the updates.

Comment: Sent to the window WM_PAINT. If you try to take a screenshot using DirectShow, there is no effect. If you try to get the tools under Windows, forms, displays: The handle is invalid.